# Stop scroll in flash based game in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have embedded a flash game in a website but whenever I try to play the game the focus shifts and websites scrolls down. I am not a pro in JavaScript so its giving me a headache. My game is this http://oldgames.cf/2016/12/25/pac-man/
Note :- I have already tried using overflow hidden but it didn't work, I have tried many scripts to make the focus stay there but it doesn't respond 
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `object`:

```
<object align="center">
<embed src="http://www.classicgamesarcade.com/games/pacman.swf" width="415px" height="500px"name="pacman" autostart="true" loop="false" controller="true">
</objec>
```